# Adding date field to attribute table using QGIS processing modeler?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, parameters, qgis-modeler

I want to add a date field to my output layers attribute table, using processing modeler. I want the Date field to be a parameter in my model, because I want to manually input the  Date everytime I run my model. Is there a way to do this, so the Date appears as a parameter before running the model (as shown in the picture) and the date entered then appears in the attribute table under a field titled Date. I want to give each layer I create a Date in the attribute table without having to edit the model each time.

I am new to QGIS.

[image: Processing model parameter]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your QGIS modeler, add the **Field Calculator** algorithm as shown in the image below. I notice in your image that you have "Date" as a parameter name and you also want to use "Date" as a field name. Change the parameter name to another such as "Enter date", don't make it the same name.

In the **Field Calculator** settings, add "Date" in the *Result field name* option and you can type or select "Enter Date" from the dropdown menu in the *Formula* option:

[image: Modeler]

If you use `Date` as the *Field type* (as in the image), the format you enter **must** be `'YYYY-MM-DD'`(**note the single quotes!**). If you want to use another format then use `String` as the *Field type* (remember to increase the *Field length*), you can then enter anything you like in whatever format you like.

[image: Running model]

[image: Result]